# Exception Type: ValueError Exception Value:too many values to unpack - Django

Tags: django, select, django-forms, django-templates, django-widget

I'm getting this error when I'm rendering the below from as (form.as_ul)

```
class InputParametersForm(ModelForm):

sqlConnection = SQLSeverConnection('MSSQLServerDataSource')
tableChoices = {'id': 'value'}
sqlQuery = sqlConnection.getTableNames()

for id in sqlQuery:
    tableChoices['id'] = id

for value in sqlQuery:
    tableChoices['value'] = value

TableName = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(tableChoices),
                              choices=tableChoices)

ColumnName = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select())

StartDateTime = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget())

EndDateTime = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget())

class Meta:
    model = SelectionHistory
    fields = ("TableName", "ColumnName", "StartDateTime", "EndDateTime")
```

This breaking onyl occurs when I ass the choices to my TableName widget, am I supplying the choices wrongly?

I'm using a dictionary of two columns (both of the same type to populate the html select box) but previously supplied only the list of table names and recieved the error Exception Type:   ValueError
Exception Value: need more than 1 value to unpack

Answer (score 0):

The `choices` attribute of a `django.forms.ChoiceField` must be an iterable (tuple or list) of tuples, [here is the relevant part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices)

```
tableChoices = (('id', 'value'), )  # or [('id', 'value')]
```

EDIT:

Since `sqlQuery` contains `pyodbc.row` objects you should create your choices like so

```
tableChoices = ((row.id, row.value) for row in sqlQuery)
```

replacing `row.id` and `row.value` for the values you want out of the query

Comment: Ok thanks for that, implented your suggestion but am getting another error; Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: What type of objects does `sqlQuery` return? Since `tableChoices` is no longer a dict the following line does not make sense `tableChoices['id'] = id` you cannot use the string `'id'` as an index

Comment: id was never an index, it was a column in my previous dict obj

Comment: What types of objects are in your `sqlQuery` object?

Comment: will be  a pyodbc.row object